# Better way to prove the closure of a set

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, ring-theory

The method I've been using to prove the closure of a set $(\Bbb Z/N\Bbb Z, +)$ under addition is to list the pairs of possible elements, apply the operation and determine if the result has the same form as the elements of this set. For example:

$Nk + Nk$
$Nk+Nk+1$
$Nk+Nk+2$
$Nk+Nk+3$
$...$
$Nk+1+Nk+1$
$Nk+1+Nk+2$
$Nk+1+Nk+3$
$...$
$Nk+N-1+Nk+N-1$

This is easy for $\Bbb Z/2Z$ and $\Bbb Z/3Z$ but becomes tedious for $\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$ and so on.

What is a better way to test if a set like $(\Bbb Z/N\Bbb Z,+)$ is closed?

Comment: It is hard to understand why you’re *proving* “closure” when the operation is *defined* to be closed. $x+N + y+N$ is $x+y+N$ by definition.  Also, it looks like you don’t properly understand what cosets are. It is not really about “setwise operations”

Comment: @rschwieb No. $(x+N)+(y+N)$ is defined as $\{x+n_1+y+n_2:\ n_1,n_2\in N\}$ As a consequence of $N$ being a (normal) subgroup this is equal to $\{x+y+n:\ n\in N\}=x+y+N$.

Comment: @rschwieb  I'm a bit confused. I never heard of cosets. My assignment just asks if $(\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z,+)$ is a group. So I have to prove if it is a closure but I don't understand how to do it.

Comment: The elements of $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ are subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ of the form $\{a+5n:\ n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$. This subset in particular is denoted $a+5\mathbb{Z}$, where the operations are understood as addition and multiplication of sets: $A+B:=\{x+y:\ x\in A,\ y\in B\}$ and $AB:=\{xy:\ x\in A,\ y\in B\}$. People call the subsets $a+5\mathbb{Z}$ for different $a\in \mathbb{Z}$, *cosets* of the subgroup $5\mathbb{Z}\subset\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: When you take two of those special subsets (cosets) and add them using the addition for sets: $(a+5\mathbb{Z})+(b+5\mathbb{Z})$ you get another set, which you need to prove is equal to $(a+b)+5\mathbb{Z}$. An element of the first would be $(a+5n_1)+(b+5n_2)$. But this is equal to $(a+b)+5(n_1+n_2)$, which is an element of the second set (here we are using that $5\mathbb{Z}$ is closed under $+$, since it is a subgroup). Conversely, an element of the second set is of the form $(a+n)+5n$. But this can be written $(a+5n)+(b+5\cdot 0)$, which belongs to the first.

Comment: Therefore $(a+5\mathbb{Z})+(b+5\mathbb{Z})=(a+b)+5\mathbb{Z}$. This proves that addition of those cosets is closed. There is another check to be done. That it is well defined. The thing is that if $a_1-a_2$ is multiple of $5$, then $a_1+5\mathbb{Z}=a_2+5\mathbb{Z}$. So maybe if we do the addition above with $a_2+5\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $a_1+5\mathbb{Z}$ we get a different result. This would prevent addition of cosets from being a function (even though it is closed).

Comment: @blueInk No. It's a common pedagogical mistake which sets people up for problems [with rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1450996/29335). If you look in most basic resources, say Wikipedia, Mathworld, or basic group theory texts, you'll find it is as I described.  The whole point of cosets is to *forget that they are sets and start thinking of them as points.*

Comment: @blueInk I would be interesting in knowing which sources you have prefer the definition you gave. I only found someone's personal notes using that, but I didn't search very long.

Comment: @David Well, it's going to be pretty hard to solve the problem if you don't know what cosets are. Thats what $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ represents: the set of cosets.

Comment: @rschwieb It is not a pedagogical mistake. It is the origin of the concept. The first book I opened, a classic, Kurosh's The Theory of Groups has it that way.

Comment: @blueInk Well, putting aside curt dismissals for a second, it still has the weakness I refer to. The fact is that $(r+I)(s+I)\neq \{(r+i_1)(s+i_2)\mid i_1,i_2\in I\}$ for ring cosets, and unfortunately that is precisely what this notion prepares a student to think.  And even by your definition, it makes the quotient operation closed by definition, so it isn't really on-topic enough to continue a debate in the comments here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set ${\Bbb Z}/N{\Bbb Z}$ is the set of cosets $a+N{\Bbb Z}$, which they
$$a+N{\Bbb Z}=\{a+Nk:k\in\Bbb Z\}.$$

The operation among them is 
$$(a+N{\Bbb Z})+(b+N{\Bbb Z})=a+b+N{\Bbb Z}.$$

For an elementary grasp think as:
$$0+5{\Bbb Z}=\{\mbox{multiples of $5$}\}$$
$$1+5{\Bbb Z}=\{\mbox{multiples of $5$ plus $1$}\}$$
$$2+5{\Bbb Z}=\{\mbox{multiples of $5$ plus $2$}\}$$
$$3+5{\Bbb Z}=\{\mbox{multiples of $5$ plus $3$}\}$$
$$4+5{\Bbb Z}=\{\mbox{multiples of $5$ plus $4$}\}$$

Note that $5+5{\Bbb Z}=\{\mbox{multiples of $5$ plus $5$}\}=0+5{\Bbb Z}$, but also
$6+5{\Bbb Z}=1+5{\Bbb Z}$, etc.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I never heard of cosets. My assignment just asks if $(\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z,+)$ is a group. So I have to prove if it is a closure but I don't understand how to do it.

Comment: ${\Bbb Z}/5{\Bbb Z}$ has only five elements: $$0+5{\Bbb Z}$$ $$1+5{\Bbb Z}$$ $$2+5{\Bbb Z}$$ $$3+5{\Bbb Z}$$ $$4+5{\Bbb Z}$$ and if you operate among then you must reduce the result as in this example: $3+5{\Bbb Z}+4+5{\Bbb Z}=7+5{\Bbb Z}=2+5{\Bbb Z}$

Comment: I'm still not sure how to prove it's a closure without adding up every pair.

Comment: if you read carefully the comments from bluelnk above maybe you should get a better picture... however if you still don’t get it... ask more... try to locate the exact point where you are still missing